# NOTEPAD++ find and replace CR/LF between ~ and ~

Tags: replace

I am trying to find all CR/LF between ~ and ~ using notepad plus

[sample text]https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0j73.jpg

I've tried ((?:^|\r\n)[^\~]+"[^\r\n"]+)\r\n([^\~]*+")

Answer (score 0):

Just searching for `~\r\n~` should work. Your attached text doesn't show those characters together.

See [Jamie Thomson's post on Replacing CRLF with LF using Notepad++](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/08/07/replacing-crlf-with-lf-using-notepad.aspx).